# VB.NET GetClientRect() returns nothing for child process in WinForm

Tags: .net, winforms, spy++, freerdp, getclientrect

Writing a WinForm project in VB.NET on VS 2017, and I am opening an instance of [FreeRDP](http://www.freerdp.com/) in `SplitContainer2.Panel1`. This works just fine, but I would like to scale the form to initially fit the FreeRDP window. In order to do this, I first need to know the size of the FreeRDP instance.

Unfortunately, every attempt I have made returns nothing. I am trying to use `GetClientRect()` from the Windows API, but all I ever get back is 0's (or nothing, I suppose). This is the first time I have played with API calls, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have verified I have the correct handle with a break in VS

(I apologize if these scale poorly. Hard to judge on scaled 4k)

[image]

compared to Spy++

[image]

So, I have confirmed I have the correct hWnd handle, but when I call a `GetClientRect()`, I get nothing back.

Here is the relevant code:

```
Dim rdpWnd As New IntPtr
Dim proc As New Process

Private Declare Auto Function GetClientRect Lib "user32.dll" ( _
    ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal lpRect As RECT) As Boolean

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Private Structure RECT
    Private Left As Short
    Private Top As Short
    Private Right As Short
    Private Bottom As Short
End Structure

Private Sub Form_Load( _
    sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo With {
        .FileName = """" & appPath & "\console\wfreerdp.exe""",
        .Arguments = "/parent-window:" & SplitContainer2.Panel1.Handle.ToString() & " /t:" & vmId
    }
    proc = Process.Start(startInfo)

    rdpWnd = getWindowHandle(Me.Text, vmId)
End Sub

Private Function getWindowHandle(caption As String, Guid As String) As IntPtr

    Dim hWnd As IntPtr = FindWindow(Nothing, caption)
    If hWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    .......

    Dim hWndRdp As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(hWndChild4, IntPtr.Zero, Nothing, Guid)
    If hWndRdp.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Return hWndRdp
End Function
```

At this point, I am looking at a console window of a Hyper-V VM in my form, but when I click the proverbial Button1...

```
Private Sub Button1_MouseClick( _
    sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseClick

    Dim myRect As New RECT
    GetClientRect(rdpWnd, myRect)
    Dim rdpWndWidth As Short = myRect.Right - myRect.Left
    Dim rdpWndHeight As Short = myRect.Bottom - myRect.Top
    MsgBox("Width: " & rdpWndWidth & vbCrLf & 
           "Height: " & rdpWndHeight)
End Sub
```

The `MsgBox()` returns:

[image]

and the variables in VS:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Why can I not get the client size when I can clearly see Spy++ can? I have spent many hours trying to figure this out, and I would appreciate the assistance in getting this milestone checked-off. About to move onto something else and come back later if I can't get it soon.

Comment: Where and how do you set `rdpWnd` ?

Comment: Updated the code. I could post the whole function if needed, but we can see from the screenshots of VS and Spy++, I have the correct handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the `RECT` struct *by value* to `GetClientRect`. This creates a copy of the struct. As a result, the original `RECT` value is never modified by the method call, and so all its fields will have default values (i.e. zero).

Change your method signature to

```
Private Declare Auto Function GetClientRect Lib "user32.dll" ( _
    ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByRef lpRect As RECT) As Boolean
```

(note the `ByRef` keyword).

Comment: Okay, that got me THAT much closer, and thank you! You were correct, but now I got an exception. I am not sure how to post an image in a reply, but essentially I am expecting "Top" to be 0, and bottom to be "768", but I am seeing Top=3298534884352 and Bottom=0. Something not right there! LOL

Comment: Any idea for the discrepancy?

Comment: @Mako-Wish, it also happens that you're using the wrong *type* for the fields of your `RECT` struct. They should be `Integer` (`System.Int32`), not `Short` (`System.Int16`).

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.